# Strange jQuery341022345155297664432 defined on window when using Webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, webpack-encore

I have a Webpack project where I am using jQuery and bootstrap like this:

```js
// js/app.js

import $ from "jquery";
import "bootstrap";

// $('.selector').find(...)
```

Webpack configured like this using Encore:

```js
// webpack.config.js

var Encore = require("@symfony/webpack-encore");

if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
  Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || "dev");
}

Encore
  .setOutputPath("public/build/")
  .setPublicPath("/build")

  .addEntry("app", "./js/app.js")

  // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
  .splitEntryChunks()

  .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
  .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
  .enableBuildNotifications()
  .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
  .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

  .configureBabelPresetEnv(config => {
    config.useBuiltIns = "usage";
    config.corejs = 3;
  })

  .enableSassLoader()
  .enablePostCssLoader()

  .copyFiles({
    from: "./assets/images",
    to: "images/[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]"
  })

  .autoProvidejQuery()

  .enableReactPreset();

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

I have noticed that a strange `window.jQuery341088885197974261661` (the `341088885197974261661` number part changes whenever I reload) keeps getting defined globally on `window` whenever I load/reload the page and has the following shape:

```js
{
    "events": {
        "load": [
            {
                "type": "load",
                "origType": "load",
                "guid": 4,
                "namespace": "bs.button.data-api"
            },
            {
                "type": "load",
                "origType": "load",
                "guid": 6,
                "namespace": "bs.carousel.data-api"
            },
            {
                "type": "load",
                "origType": "load",
                "guid": 13,
                "namespace": "bs.data-api.scrollspy"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The object also has a `handle` method defined like this in the jquery.js source (line 5039):

```js
    ...
            eventHandle = elemData.handle = function( e ) {

                // Discard the second event of a jQuery.event.trigger() and
                // when an event is called after a page has unloaded
                return typeof jQuery !== "undefined" && jQuery.event.triggered !== e.type ?
                    jQuery.event.dispatch.apply( elem, arguments ) : undefined;
            };
    ...
```

What is this `window.jQuery341088885197974261661` object and how can I avoid to keep defining it on `window` so that everything in my bundle stays local?

Thanks!

Comment: This is how usually jQuery defines a unique jquery callback for ajax calls

Comment: Mmm, I am not making any AJAX calls with `jQuery`... Could it be related to `bootstrap`? Look at those `"namespace": "bs.*.data-api"`...

Comment: Yeah it can be as well, what I wan't to say is that it is normal & not related to webpack

Comment: So there's no way to get rid of it, isn't it?

Comment: Not loading / using jQuery :]

Comment: I have found out that it's jQuery that adds this object through the `expando` property `expando: "jQuery" + ( version + Math.random() ).replace( /\D/g, "" ),`